# Is there a fully featured OBB class for Ogre3D?

Tags: bounding-box, ogre

Is there a fully featured OBB class for Ogre3D?
I don't think there is one by default but I am looking for an alternative which has all the features of the AxisAlignedBox class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are implementations around, which are not integrated in Ogre's core, since this is usually covered by physics engines and does not fall into the main area of a rendering engine:

One implementation example can be found in the Ore wiki article [Object Bounding Box](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Oriented%20Bounding%20Box). Its [talk page](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Talk%3aOriented%20Bounding%20Box), also got a few helpful code lines.